# Use of "one of" with "and" and "or."

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is either of the following is proper?

- *Are you related to one of George or Mike?*
- *Are you related to one of George and Mike?*

I'd like to ask a yes-or-no question to determine whether you are related to at least one the individuals George and Mike.

Comment: I'd use _or_. The only reason you add _one of_ is to disambiguate the question _Are you related to George or Mike?_ (it could be asking which you're related to, rather than a yes/no question).

Comment: *Are you related to either George or Mike?* or *Are you related to either of George or Mike?*

Comment: *Are you related to George or Mike?* or *Are you related to one of George and Mike?* Since *one of* logically requires a group to select from, *George or Mike* just doesn't fit.

Answer (score 2):

"Are you related to George and/or Mike?"

Some people don't like the "and/or" construction, and some people *really* don't like it when it's spoken rather than written. Unless you need to be especially formal, though, I would say that the advantage of eliminating the need to clarify the question further is likely to outweigh the awkwardness of it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is certainly "and", but it is not always obvious. In the specific question you might be related to both George and Mike, which I think makes it a confusing example.

Suppose we rephrase the question to be an exclusive 1-of-n choice, and compare the two phrases:

- Choose red, blue, green or yellow.
- Choose one of red, blue, green and yellow.

The phrases seem almost the same and it's easy to see why you might use "or" in the second phrase. In spoken language I don't think anyone would notice.

Logically, you can think of the second phrase as meaning:

- Choose one from this list.
- The list is red, blue, green and yellow.

It would not be logical to use "or" in defining the list, so it just as illogical to use it in the phrase with "Choose one of".

That being said, language does not always follow logic.

Comment: "Language does not always follow logic."  But you have just used logic to justify the claim that '[t]he answer is certainly "and" '.  No; what is needed is evidence of which one of these a sizable group of native speakers actually use (and it could be a split decision). As CS Lewis once said about another attempt to prove correctness by logic: "Don't take any notice of teachers and text-books in such matters. Nor of logic. It is good to say 'More than one passenger was hurt,' although more than one equals at least two and therefore logically the verb ought to be plural were not singular was!"

Comment: Good point, but sadly I cannot provide this evidence.